# Using multiple delimiters for .split in Java

Tags: java, string, split

Right now my code only separates words by white space, but I also want to separate by '.' and "," too. Here is my current code:

```
for (String words : input.split("\\s+"))
```

For example, if the user entered "bread,milk,eggs" or "Um...awkss" It would consider that one word, and I want each word to be it's own word.

And while I'm here, I can't get

```
input.isAlpha()
```

to work either.

Comment: The canonical list of regular expressions you can use is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html - it's not a tutorial, but there are plenty of other tutorials around.

Comment: `isAlpha` is C.  In Java it's called `isLetter`.  Read http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/ChecksiftheStringcontainsonlyunicodeletters.htm

Comment: I want to use isAlpha(or what ever it is for java) on a string, not a char. My compiler is telling me that isLetter is only for chars. Thanks for the link btw.

Comment: Well, the link I gave you will tell you one way of doing that.  Not the only way, but one way.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was a method in Java, but that would work too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can split using this regex

```
input.split("\\s+|.+|,+")
```

or simply:

```
input.split("[\\s.,]+")
```

Remember that [a dot doesn't have to be escaped inside square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976308/1961634)

Comment: Curious, why is \\s+ the regex for whitespace, \\. the one for period, but for comma you only need the comma?

Comment: period is a special character in regex; `\\` is the escape sequence. As I said, try to learn more about regex. Find a tutorial or sth.

Comment: @Dariusz why you escape `.` if you already did in by placing it inside `[]`?

Comment: `.` doesn't need to be escaped inside brackets

Comment: Don't need the `+` after `\\s` in the square brackets.

Comment: @Spork if you are asking about regex tutorial suggestions then one of best is http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 5):

Use brackets

```
for (String words : input.split("[\\s.,]+"))
```

Brackets are used when you want any of the characters in the brackets, the `+` means the characters can be combined one or more times. to create one single delimiter, i.e. `space and period` or `comma and space`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
mySring = "abc==abc++abc==bc++abc";
String[] splitString = myString.split("\\W+");
```

> Regular expression \W+ ---> it will split the string based upon non-word character.