# Mistaken Squid Proxy regex? → ^.*stackoverflow\.*

Tags: regex, squid

I have several proxy rule files for Squid, and all contain rules like:

```
acl blacklisted dstdom_regex ^.*facebook\.* ^.*youtube\.* ^.*games.yahoo.com\.*
```

The patterns match against the domain name: **dstdom_regex** means *[destination (server) regular expression pattern matching](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#ACL_elements)*.

The objective is to block some websites, but I don't know by what method: domain name, keywords in the domain name, ...

Let's expand/describe the pattern:

```
^.*stackexchange\.*     The whole pattern
^                       String beginning
 .*                     Match anything (greedy quantifier, I presume)
   stackexchange        Keyword to match
                \.*     Any number of dots (.)
```

Totally legitimate matches:

- `stackexchange.com`: The Stack Exchange website.
- `stackoverflow.stackexchange`: The imaginary Stack Exchange gTLD.

But these possible matches make it seem more like a keyword block:

- `stackexchange`
- `stackexchanger`
- `notstackexchange`
- `not-stackexchange`
- `some-website.stackexchange`
- `some-website.stackexchange-tld`

And the pattern seems to contain a bug, since it allows the following invalid cases to match, thanks to the `\.*` at the end, although they never naturally occur:

- `stackexchange.`
- `stackexchange...`
- `stackexchange..........`
- `stackexchange.......com`
- `stackexchange.com`
- `stackexchangecom`
- you get the idea.

Anything containing `stackexchange`, even if separated by dots from everything else, is still a valid match.

---

**So now, the question itself:**

This all means that this is simply a match for `stackexchange`! (I'm assuming the original author didn't intend to match infinite dots.)

So why not just use the pattern `stackexchange`? Wouldn't it be faster and give the same results, except for the "bug" (`\.*`)?

I.e., isn't `^.*stackexchange` equivalent to `stackexchange`?

---

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I didn't write those proxy rule files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use `\.*` to match all the following dots

However to bypass your problem you can try this out :

- `^[^\.]*\.stackexchange\.*`

`[^\.]*` matches anything except a dot 
`\.` then you match the dot

edit : formatting

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't write those proxy rule files. Me too, I don't understand why the `\.*` is used there!

Comment: Ok, essentially you just want to test if the current URL is from a certain domain : `^[^\.]*\.stackexchange.*` might be better then

Comment: I only know these rules are intended to block some websites, but I don't know if who wrote them decided to block keywords instead of domains.

Comment: Are you sure about the `\ ` in `[^\.]`? Within character classes a `.` doesn't need to be escaped since it has no special meaning. It makes no sense to use it as a wildcard inside a character class.

Comment: `[^\.]` means : any char except `\.` which is literally the `.`

Comment: Are you sure? Usually you don't need to escape the `.` inside a character class, but I don't know about Squid. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19976308