# Trying to remove a range of characters from the middle of a string in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to remove the middle portion ('G0G90E1' and 'M3S3000') of a string. However, the length from the start to the end will vary, and the number after the 'S' will vary, too (Ex: 'S500', 'S10000', etc.). I'm trying to format this string, which is in ShowContentsOfFile.Text:

```
'G0G90E1X0Y0M3S3000
'X0Y0
'X1Y1
```

To this, BUT, only for the copies (which are show in 'E2' and below), which is what the For, Next loop is doing, so, for example, it'll look like this, when I make, say, 5 parts:

```
'G0G90E1X0Y0M3S3000
'X0Y0
'X1Y1
'E2X0Y0
'X0Y0
'X1Y1
'E3X0Y0
'X0Y0
'X1Y1
'E4X0Y0
'X0Y0
'X1Y1
'E5X0Y0
'X0Y0
'X1Y1
```

Unfortunately, it also gets rid of the lines below 'E1':

```
'X0Y0
'X1Y1
```

Here's my code:

```
    If NumberOfParts.Text = NumberOfParts.Text Then

        Dim CopySpecificText As String = ShowContentsOfFile.Text

        Dim Start As Integer = CopySpecificText.IndexOf("E1")
        Dim Finish As Integer = CopySpecificText.IndexOf("M")

        Dim DynamicString As String
        Dim x As Integer

        CopySpecificText = CopySpecificText.Replace("G0G90E1", "").Substring(Start, Finish - Start).Trim

        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(CopySpecificText)

        For x = 1 To NumberOfParts.Text - 1

            DynamicString = "E" & x + 1
            ShowContentsOfFile.Text += Environment.NewLine & DynamicString & Clipboard.GetText

        Next x

    End If
```

Comment: You are trying to re-invent the [Mid statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz5s6003.aspx), easier to just use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split up the first line with a *regular expression* into the letter+digit(s) parts, e.g. "G0", "G90", "E1", "X0", "Y0", "M3", "S3000".

Then from that you can select the parts you want repeated (e.g. "E1X0Y0") by checking the first character of each part and joining together the chosen parts.

I assumed that the "E" could have a number other than 1 and that you would want to start from that number and add on the number of parts specified in `NumberOfParts`. I also allowed for there being one-or-more lines after the first line:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Sub MakeNewText()
        Dim copySpecificText() As String = ShowContentsOfFile.Lines
        ' could use Integer.TryParse here to make sure a valid number has been entered:
        Dim nParts = CInt(NumberOfParts.Text)

        ' split the first line into letter-digits pieces and discard the resulting empty parts...
        Dim parts = Regex.Split(copySpecificText(0), "([A-Z][0-9]*)").Where(Function(p) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).ToList()

        ' to show the parts which were found:
        'ShowContentsOfFile.AppendText(vbCrLf & "Found parts:")
        'For Each p In parts
        '   ShowContentsOfFile.AppendText(vbCrLf & p)
        'Next
        'ShowContentsOfFile.AppendText(vbCrLf & "---")

        ' extract the parts starting with certain letters into a string...
        Dim wantedCodes = "EXY".ToCharArray()
        Dim wantedParts = String.Join("", parts.Where(Function(p) wantedCodes.Contains(p.Chars(0))))

        ' get a string of the X and Y parts...
        Dim xyCodes = "XY".ToCharArray()
        Dim xyString = String.Join("", parts.Where(Function(p) xyCodes.Contains(p.Chars(0))))

        ' get the number from the "E" section:
        Dim eFirstIndex = CInt(parts.First(Function(p) p.StartsWith("E")).Substring(1))
        ' calculate the last index:
        Dim eLastIndex = eFirstIndex + nParts - 1

        For i = eFirstIndex To eLastIndex
            ShowContentsOfFile.AppendText(vbCrLf & "E" & i.ToString() & xyString)
            ShowContentsOfFile.AppendText(vbCrLf & String.Join(vbCrLf, copySpecificText.Skip(1)))

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MakeNewText()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' put test data into the text controls:
        NumberOfParts.Text = "5"
        ShowContentsOfFile.Text = "G0G90E1X0Y0M3S3000" & vbCrLf & "X0Y0" & vbCrLf & "X1Y1"

    End Sub

End Class
```

Result from the above code:

```
G0G90E1X0Y0M3S3000
X0Y0
X1Y1
E1X0Y0
X0Y0
X1Y1
E2X0Y0
X0Y0
X1Y1
E3X0Y0
X0Y0
X1Y1
E4X0Y0
X0Y0
X1Y1
E5X0Y0
X0Y0
X1Y1
```

That code should be a bit more modifiable than the code you're trying, although I guess it is G-code and you won't need to modify the program once you have it working.

Comment: It works! However, I forgot a small detail. Whenever the numbers after the X and/or Y after the E are decimals, negative numbers, or negative decimals, some numbers get skipped! I tried adding [.-] to Regex, and I thought it worked, but it still skips the numbers! :(

Comment: @BonsSilva In that case, I think you need `([A-Z][0-9.-]*)` as the regex. N.B. [Does a dot have to be escaped in a character class (square brackets) of a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19976308/1115360) et seq.