# Remove illegal characters from a file name but leave spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following line of code to remove illegal characters from a file name:

```
str= str.replace(/([^a-z0-9]+)/gi, '-');
```

That works fine but it also removes the spaces, how can I only remove the illegal characters but leave the spaces?

Comment: How do you determine "illegal" character? Your regex says that `.`,`_` and many other characters are "illegal", Why?

Comment: Just add the space to the class `[^a-z0-9 ]` that way it won't get matched (removed).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Illegal characters are listed [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words). To replace them use this regex `/[/\\?%*:|"<>]/g` like this:

```js
var filename = "f?:i/le>  n%a|m\\e.ext";

filename = filename.replace(/[/\\?%*:|"<>]/g, '-');

console.log(filename);
```

Comment: These characters depend on OS. Under Linux you can have any character, even space in a filename.

Comment: @Toto I excluded the case of `.` and ` ` because they aren't really illegal!

Comment: You missed unprintable characters in ascii-range 0-31 (inclusive).

Comment: You need to escape these characters: `/[\/\\\?\%\*\:\|\"\<\>]/g`

Comment: @EugeneP. there is [no need to escape those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976308/9867451) because inside a character class, they are considered literals.

Comment: @hallo this is actually the most correct answer. It should be a block-list because usually OS (Windows, Linux (android too), macOS) supports non-ASCII characters as well
You can't ignore those because that can be useful to the user. So technically downvote for u

Answer (score 8):

You are searching for all non numeric and roman letters.  If you want to exclude the space from being replaced:

***Just add a space to the selection to exclude :)***

```
str= str.replace(/([^a-z0-9 ]+)/gi, '-');
// add a space here -------^
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I understand what you mean, could you explain?

Comment: Your regexp looks to match characters that are not: lowercase characters from a-z, uppercase from A-Z and numbers from 0-9, and replaces the match.  To avoid replacing spaces, adding a space as I've recommended will achieve what you want because you're trying to match anything _**not**_ included between the `[ .. ]` square brackets

Comment: This solution isn't correct. Because it'll also replace all valid non-ASCII chars as well

Answer (score 8):

You can use \W+

> \W (non-word-character) matches any single character that doesn't match by \w (same as [^a-zA-Z0-9_])
>   **Source:** https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html

```
str = str.replace(/(\W+)/gi, '-');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the '\s' whitespace to your exclusion.

```
str = str.replace(/([^a-z0-9\s]+)/gi, '-');
```