# Write a regex for usernames

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I want a Regex for my mongoose schema to test if a username contains only letters, numbers and underscore, dash or dot. What I got so far is

```regex
/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]/
```

but somehow it lets pass everything.

Comment: What does it match when it shouldn't? Can you give some example inputs, expected output and the actual output?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is set to match a string if it contains ANY of the contained characters, but it doesn't make sure that the string is composed entirely of those characters.

For example, `/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]/.test("a&")` returns true, because the string contains the letter `a`, regardless of the fact that it also includes `&`.

To make sure all characters are one of your desired characters, use a regex that matches the beginning of the string `^`, then your desired characters followed by a quantifier `+` (a plus means one or more of the previous set, a `*` would mean zero or more), then end of string `$`. So:

```js
const reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+$/

console.log(reg.test("")) // false
console.log(reg.test("I-am_valid.")) // true
console.log(reg.test("I-am_not&")) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this with start(`^`) and end(`$`),

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+$
```

[image]

See demo : https://regex101.com/r/6v0nNT/3

Comment: Tiny nitpick, it turns out that when a `.` appears in a character group (inside `[]`, it is already interpreted literally and there's no need to escape it.

Answer (score -1):

> /^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[-_\.])*$/

This regex should work.

^ matches at the beginning of the string. $ matches at the end of the string. This means it checks for the entire string.

The * allows it to match any number of characters or sequences of characters. This is required to match the entire password.

Now the parentheses are required for this as there is a | (or) used here. The first stretch was something you already included, and it is for capital/lowercase letters, and numbers. The second area of brackets are used for the other characters. The . must be escaped with a backslash, as it is a reserved character in regex, used for denoting that something can be any character.

Comment: You don't need to escape dots when they are part of a character class.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976018/does-a-dot-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-character-class-square-brackets-of-a-regula