# Regex expression with [ and * in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with lines like this

```
variable = epms[something][something]
```

I need to find these lines by searching for epms.

Currently, I am trying this:

```
regex = re.compile('[.]*epms\[[.]*\]\[[.]*\][.]*')
```

However this doesn't find any match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[.]` matches a literal dot char. You need to remove the `[]` around `.`s.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976018/does-a-dot-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-character-class-square-brackets-of-a-regula

Comment: Try  \^*epms\[.*?\]\[.*?\]

Comment: If you are looking for exact string, why do you use regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern:

```
epms\[[^]]+\]\[[^]]+\]
```

- `epms` Match literal substring.
- `\[` Match a `[`.
- `[^]]+` Negated character set. Anything other than a `]`.
- `\]` Match a `]`.
- `\[` Match a `[`.
- `[^]]+` Negated character set. Anything other than a `]`.
- `\]` Match a `]`.

In Python:

```
import re

mystring = "variable = epms[something][something]"
if re.search(r'epms\[[^]]+\]\[[^]]+\]',mystring):
    print (mystring)
```

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern `epms\[.*\]\[.*\]`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

with open(filename1) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if re.search(r"epms\[.*\]\[.*\]", line):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, tested in Python3:

```
>>> s = 'variable = epms[something][something]'
>>> re.match(r'.*epms\[.*\]\[.*\]', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 37), match='variable = epms[something][something]'>
```

You don't need square brackets to identify 'any characters'.