# Javascript error when using divStyle.match

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

```
var values = divStyle.match( /-?[\d\.]+/g );
```

The above code is giving me an `error` when I run `yarn build`.

> error: unnecessary escape character: `\.  no-useless-escape`

How do I fix this?

Comment: The `.` inside character set is always a *period* character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered here: [Does a dot have to be escaped in a character class (square brackets) of a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976018/does-a-dot-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-character-class-square-brackets-of-a-regula)

> In a character class (square brackets) any character except ^, -, ] or \ is a literal.

So in your case simply do not escape the dot:

```
var values = divStyle.match( /-?[\d.]+/g );
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. I didn't understand the issue enough to connect it to the other question.