# Regex using brackets for a single character

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I was solving this regex problem

> Given a test string, s , write a RegEx that matches s under the following conditions:
>
> s must start with Mr., Mrs., Ms., Dr. or Er.
>
> The rest of the string must contain only one or more English alphabetic letters (upper and lowercase).

I used this pattern

```
Regex_Pattern = r'^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\..[A-Za-z]+$'
```

but it failed this test case "Ms._underscore", then I tried using this pattern

```
Regex_Pattern = r'^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)[\..][A-Za-z]+$'
```

and it passed all test cases, I cannot figure out the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, we can visualize our expressions and check:

[image]

[image]

We can see that the difference is here, between `\..` and `[\..]`.

- In the first one, we are saying that we must have a `.` followed by any char.
- In the second, we want to just pass one of `.` or `.`, which is equal to `[.]`.

#### [Demo for second expression](https://regex101.com/r/Tmmmkv/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

Comment: did you mean "In the second, we want to just pass one of '.' or 'any char', which is equal to [.]"?

Comment: @omar Yes, in the second case you take _either_ since that's what a character class `[]` does -- it matches either one of what is listed inside.  (While the first case requires to have both `.` and another character.)   Emma -- needs to be `[\..]` in the second case, not `[..]`.

Comment: @omar I didn't really finish the statement I meant to make (which may or may not be obvious?) --  in the first case it matches _one_ thing only, in the second case it requires _two_. So this makes a difference for whether it matches or not the whole thing, with patterns before and after it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have the two patterns reversed.  The second one does not match and the first one matches:

`^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\..[A-Za-z]+$`
[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/4On3bm/1)

`^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)[\..][A-Za-z]+$`
[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/4On3bm/2)

The second one uses character class `[\..]` which removes special meaning of any regex tokens (e.g., `.` within `[]` matches literal period and not its special meaning (any character).  The first pattern matches a literal period followed by any single character other than newline.  For details on this, check out the "Explanation" on the right side in the demo links above.

UPDATE: your pattern also would match *Ms.underscore* (no space between title and name). So consider the following pattern, which I think works better for what you're looking for:

`^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\.[ _][A-Za-z]+$`
[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/4On3bm/3)

Comment: I was misunderstanding something, I thought "\.." as a whole was the escape for ".", I think it was just a "period" in the tutorial :).
But thanks to this mistake I now know that not I do not need to escape most of special characters inside brackets.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976018/does-a-dot-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-character-class-square-brackets-of-a-regula