# How to write RegExp string in VScode, it always be corrected

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

VSCode always autofixs the Regexp string:

> `new RegExp("^[0-9\.]+$", "i")`

to

> `new RegExp("^[0-9.]+$", "i")`

Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: [Escaping `.` inside square brackets is unnecessary.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976018/does-a-dot-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-character-class-square-brackets-of-a-regula) Anyway, *when* does this autofix happen? When you save? Or...?

Comment: well, it seems work, dude~ @juzraai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perfectly fine - *if* you want to match a number or a literal dot `.`. If you want to match a number, a literal dot, *and* a **literal backslash**, you need to escape the backslash:

```
new RegExp("^[0-9.\\]+$", "i")
```

You could use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw):

```
new RegExp(String.raw`^[0-9.\\]+$`, "i")
```

Comment: @Zhaiduo Why? It unnecessarily converts the string into a substitution free template string to then use a special function to get the "raw" string. The real solution is to escape the backslash (\\\) which Jack has "slipped" unmentioned into its answer. tl;dr: escape the backslash, remove the template stuff

Comment: I still don't get why you're using a template string and `String.raw` o.O

Comment: @Andreas My intention is keep the old format of RegExp string, and let VScode ignore the autofixing. Maybe it's not for others, but best for me.

Comment: I've seen it used like that @Andreas, and I'm keeping it for the sake of the original content of the answer - unless you disapprove.