# Regex - Match a word but do not match a phrase that can appear anywhere in the phrase

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been spending time on this regex but I can't get it to work. So I need to match bunch of words in a phrase but if the same word occurs with a set of words, I do not want that to be captured. For example:

phrase: Hi, I am talking about a recall on the product I bought last month. If I recall correctly, I purchased this at your store on august 15th. Can you tell me if I can get a refund on this recall?

Result should match the first recall and the last recall. but it should not match 'If I recall' since those three words together doesn't talk about the product recall.

I tried different variations of this but couldn't get it to work. This matches all 'recall' terms.

```
(?<!If\sI\srecall).*?(recalls?|recalled).*?(?!If\sI\srecall)
```

I am using Python 3.10 to test this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the regex becomes too complex: one possible solution would be to first replace all occurrences of `If I recall` by `NOT_INTERESTING`, and look for the strings you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match the 2 words:

```
(?<!\bIf\sI\s)\brecall(?:s|ed)?\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\bIf\sI\s)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `If I`  to the left
- `\brecall(?:s|ed)?` Match one of the words `recall` `recalls` `recalled`
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ROvNH8/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/I3xUCE)

Comment: Beautiful. This perfectly worked for my case. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can try ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWnaGp/1)):

```py
import re

txt = """Hi, I am talking about a recall on the product I bought last month. If I recall correctly, I purchased this at your store on august 15th. Can you tell me if I can get a refund on this recall?"""

pat = re.compile(r"(?<!If I )(?:recalls?|recalled)", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

for phrase in re.findall(r".*?[.?!]", txt):
    if pat.search(phrase):
        print(phrase)
```

Prints:

```
Hi, I am talking about a recall on the product I bought last month.
 Can you tell me if I can get a refund on this recall?
```

Comment: This solution is great if I want to exclude the phrases that I don't want to match. This may actually come in handy for me in other problems. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I always forget that it's possible to omit escaping in brackets, as in `[.?!]`. Is there a problem to leave them, e.g. `[\.\?!]`?

Comment: Yes, for `.`, `?`, `!` the escape character can be omitted inside brackets. Of course, with `^`, `-`, `]` or `\\` you need to be more careful. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976018/does-a-dot-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-character-class-square-brackets-of-a-regula