# Regex - replace everything except string between tags in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract a string from within a string. The string contains out of html-tags.

Here is an example string:

```
<span class="artist-name">John Doe</span> <span class="artist-instrument">Violin</span>
```

All I need is the name (John Doe). Name and instrument vary. I've tried the following regex which doesn't work:

```
/\<span[ ]class=\"artist-name\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/si
```

Im working with FirstSpirit, a Java-based CMS.

Thanks!

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3282436 (Even though I think your use case is fine.)

Comment: You could split on `>` and `<` and search for element after `span class="artist-name"` ? This post explains how to split strings on multiple delimiters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967972/using-multiple-delimiters-for-split-in-java

Comment: Don’t use regular expressions for this.  Seriously.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use a dedicated library: Jericho HTML http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html, and specifically this code: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/samples/console/src/ExtractText.java

That could be a better solution than a custom regexp, which are known to be hard to maintain.

Comment: You could also parse the string as XML with Java's own XML parser. No need for a full blown HTML parser I guess.

Comment: Jericho is more tolerant to xml errors (bad formed html, missing close tags, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The code separates the string by < and >, and looks for the relevant string by looking at the remainder of the HTML element.

```
    String toTest = "<span class=\"artist-name\">John Doe</span>";
    String[] split = toTest.split("<|>");
    for(int i = 0; i < split.length-1; i++){
        if(split[i].equals("span class=\"artist-name\"")){
            System.out.println(split[i+1]);
        }
    }
```